# How to reference theme attributes in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-jetpack-compose

So in the current andriod development, if we need to reference to a color set in the theme, we could simply do: (in layout xml)

```
....
    <TextView
        ...
        android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
        .../>
....
```

If I set a color blue in the theme. I will get that color in the textview above.

I was wondering how I could do the same in `Jetpack Compose`. In `Compose`, we do,

```
MaterialTheme(...) {
    Column {
        Text(
            ...
            textStyle = TextStyle(color = ????) // How to I reference to the theme?
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using Material Design Components, you can use [Accompanist to leverage your theme resource in Compose](https://github.com/chrisbanes/accompanist/blob/main/mdc-theme/README.md).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
Text(text = "....",
     style = TextStyle(color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary))
```

Comment: What if I want to reference dimension attributes, e.g. `android.R.attr.actionBarSize`?

Comment: @SơnPhan have you find a solution for this?

Comment: Actually I didn't find anything about that, so asked it here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71033751/how-to-match-color-attributes-between-theme-and-icon-in-jetpack-compose

Answer (score 6):

For getting color from attributes I use this composable function:

```
@Composable
fun getColor(color: Int): Color {
    return colorResource(LocalContext.current.getColorFromAttrs(color).resourceId)
}

fun Context.getColorFromAttrs(attr: Int): TypedValue {
    return TypedValue().apply {
        theme.resolveAttribute(attr, this, true)
    }
}
```

Usages:

```
val color: Color = getColor(R.attr.colorText)
```

Comment: Nice one, but I preffer more conceise version: 
`@Composable
@ReadOnlyComposable
fun colorAttribute(attrColor: Int) = colorResource(TypedValue().apply { LocalContext.current.theme.resolveAttribute(attrColor, this, true) }.resourceId)`

Answer (score 4):

Compose provide `ColorPalette` based on Material color specification to generate you app theme. It provide `lightColorPalette` and `darkColorPalette` for defining theme for light and dark mode respectively.

```
val lightThemeColors = lightColorPalette(
    primary = Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
    primaryVariant = Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
    onPrimary = Color.Black,
    secondary = Color.Transparent,
    onSecondary = Color.White,
    background = Color.White,
    onBackground = Color(0xFF212121),
    surface = Color.White,
    onSurface = Color(0xFF212121),
    error = Color.Red,
    onError = Color.White
)
val darkThemeColors = darkColorPalette(
    primary = Color(0xFF000000),
    primaryVariant = Color(0xFF000000),
    onPrimary = Color.White,
    secondary = Color.White,
    onSecondary = Color.White,
    surface = Color(0xFF212121),
    background = Color(0xFF212121),
    onBackground = Color.White,
    onSurface = Color.White,
    error = Color.Red,
    onError = Color.White
)
MaterialTheme(
colors = if(isSystemInDarkTheme()) darkThemeColors else lightThemeColors
) {
    Column {
        Text(
        textStyle = TextStyle(color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
        )
    }
}
```

If you want to add more custom color to you theme you can use `ColorPalette` with extension variable like shown below

```
@Composable
val ColorPalette.myColor: Color
    get() = if(!isLight) Color(0xFF424242) else Color.White
```

Now you can use `MaterialTheme.colors.myColor` to include.

If you want to include color from android colors xml you can do that using `colorResource(id = R.color.anyName)` function.

Comment: I've not found `ColorPalette` in the current stable compose material version 1.0.3. You've to use `Colors` instead of `ColorPalette` in the above solution. And of course `@Composable` annotation is not required.

Comment: Agreed there is no `ColorPalette` and also annotation is not needed for `val` types.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Material3 you will use MaterialTheme.colorScheme:

```
Text(text = "Example",
     style = TextStyle(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
inline fun <T> Resources.Theme.getAttribute(
    @AttrRes attr: Int,
    block: (TypedArray) -> T,
): T {
    val a = obtainStyledAttributes(intArrayOf(attr))
    return block(a).also { a.recycle() }
}

fun Resources.Theme.getDrawableAttribute(@AttrRes attr: Int): Drawable =
    getAttribute(attr) { it.getDrawable(0)!! }

fun Resources.Theme.getDimensionAttribute(@AttrRes attr: Int, defaultValue: Float = 0f): Float =
    getAttribute(attr) { it.getDimension(0, defaultValue) }

fun Resources.Theme.getStringAttribute(@AttrRes attr: Int): String? =
    getAttribute(attr) { it.getString(0) }

fun Resources.Theme.getColorAttribute(@AttrRes attr: Int, defaultValue: Int = 0): Int =
    getAttribute(attr) { it.getColor(0, defaultValue) }


@Composable
fun getDimensionAttribute(@AttrRes attr: Int, defaultValue: Float = 0f): Float =
    LocalContext.current.theme.getDimensionAttribute(attr, defaultValue)

@Composable
fun getStringAttribute(@AttrRes attr: Int): String? =
    LocalContext.current.theme.getStringAttribute(attr)

@Composable
fun getColorAttribute(@AttrRes attr: Int, defaultValue: Int = 0): Int =
    LocalContext.current.theme.getColorAttribute(attr, defaultValue)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: good solution, but for me it's not working now. Does it still work for you?